# How does one access the view controller a Stack View is in?

Tags: ios, swift

I followed an [Apple Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) which basically explains how to set up views and Tables.

I modified the code, so I just showed some data when I click on a row. Now I have a Control based on a Stack view. I incorporated the Stack view using Storyboards in the Table Cell, and the View.

How can I, being either in a table cell or in a standard view, access the row my data is in so I can change it in the Array it's stored in?

[image: Pictures]

My problem is that I don't know how to access the right index.

Btw I can't add code because there is none just basic implementation.

Edit: pictures, Clarifications

Comment: Do you mean access a row in a tableView and update that rows data in your array?

Comment: you're question is unclear. Can you show us an image and say which viewController you want to access? And show some of your related code?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a delegate protocol and just forward whatever is clicked to your delegate and let it decide what to do with it. Your view should not know about the viewcontroller it is in so it remains reusable.

```
class MyControl {
    weak var delegate: MyControlDelegate?
    ...
    delegate?.myControl(self, clickedItem: theItem)
}
protocol MyControlDelegate: class{
    func myControl(_ myControl: MyControl, clickedItem: Item)
}
```

Comment: I am unable to declare the delegate variable